# Cannot add two vcpkg at the same time in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, vcpkg

I am trying to add both boost-program-options.1.82.0 and grpc.1.50.1 vcpkg with static link in visual studio.

But I don't know why only first import vcpkg can be added successfully, and the second one will get error.

If I add one vcpkg only, the build process will be successfully.

#### .vcxproj

```yaml
  <Import Project="..\packages\boost-program-options.1.82.0\build\native\boost-program-options.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\boost-program-options.1.82.0\build\native\boost-program-options.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\grpc.1.50.1\build\native\grpc.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\grpc.1.50.1\build\native\grpc.props')" />

...

  <PropertyGroup Label="Vcpkg" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <VcpkgUseStatic>true</VcpkgUseStatic>
    <VcpkgTriplet>x64-windows-static</VcpkgTriplet>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

#### code

```c
#include <grpc/support/log.h>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
```

#### erros

If I added grpc.1.50.1 first, then I will got error:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'boost/program_options.hpp': No such file or directory
```

If I added boost-program-options.1.82.0 first, then I will get error:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'grpc/support/log.h': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I added manually related include path and necessary static library to fix this issue.